# PHP UPDATE DATABASE error

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem with my code. I have a UPDATE, but it doesn't really update my DB, and i don't know why.. Can you help me? please?

```
$query = "UPDATE company SET name, address, latitude, longitude, 
about, cui, time, date, phone WHERE name=$name, address=$address, 
latitude=$latitude, longitude=$longitude, about=$about, cui=$cui,
 time=$time, date=$date, phone=$phone";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Does `$result` return `true`?

Comment: Are variables strings?

Comment: What are updating with?

Comment: Also `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP and your query might be susceptible to SQL injection

Comment: What values are you even setting? What error are you getting? Also, you should use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Use the single quotes for name, address etc fields

Comment: There are a number of things wrong here. What error are you receiving? Maybe you are trying to `insert` here and not `update`? Is this all new data?

Comment: There are so many errors here that the best thing anyone can do it point you to a MySQLi/PHP/SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not correct syntax of update.

Correct structure of UPDATE statement is:

```
UPDATE [TABLE_NAME] SET FIELD_ONE = '$FIELD_ONE', FIELD_TWO = '$FIELD_TWO'
WHERE FIELD_NAME = '$FIELD_VALUE'
```

Also, you need to add single quotes to field values who are not `INT` defined in database.

Updated Query:

```
$query = "UPDATE company SET name = '$name', address='$address', 
latitude='$latitude', longitude='$longitude', about='$about', cui='$cui',
 time='$time', date='$date', phone='$phone' 
WHERE [ADD_YOUR_CONDITION]
";
```

**NOTE:**
Don't use **mysql_** functions. They are deprecated ones and will be removed in new PHP versions. Use *PDO* or **mysqli_** instead.

Comment: Might want to add note about SQL injection possibility here as well.

Comment: I'd suggest putting an example of PDO or mysqli in here as, although the question will be deleted, if it does stay on here people may just copy and paste your code.

Comment: @ColarPaul, if my answer worked for you, please accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct syntex for [update mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

```
$query = "UPDATE company SET name='$name', address='$address', 
    latitude='$latitude', longitude='$longitude', about='$about', cui='$cui',
     time='$time', date='$date', phone='$phone'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Strings need to be quoted...

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mention `id` or some unique thing to which update 
this query will update the whole table , don't use `mysql_*` becoz its deprecated now try to use `mysqli_*`

```
 $query = "UPDATE `company` SET `name`='".$name."', `address`='".$address."', `latitude`='".$latitude."', `longitude`='".$longitude."', `about`='".$about."', `cui`='".$cui."',`time`='".$time."', `date`='".$date."', `phone`='".$phone."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You update query should be wrong.
Example of query

```
$query = "UPDATE company SET name='".$name."' WHERE name='".$name."'";
```